# calling onclick function with variable

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, onclick

```
...
<%
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
int i = 0;
while (result.next()){...

%>
 ...

<input type="button" value="drehen"
 onclick="tauscheBild(**list, i**);">
         </div>
...
```

I am trying to use my Java variables when calling the onclick function. How do I do it?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
onclick="tauscheBild('<%=VAR1%>', '<%=VAR2%>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use expression tags in JSP. Find the information you need here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html